# Unable to serialize PySpark UDF

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, lxml, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a UDF in PySpark. The function takes in an input string which is an xml. It then uses lxml to parse it and returns a list of dictionaries with the attributes. I created the function `parse_xml`, but when I try the line `spark.udf.register("parse_xml", parse_xml)` but this gives the error: `PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle lxml.etree.XMLParser objects`.

It seems as if lxml objects are not serializable, but the input is a string and the output is a list/dictionary -- is there any way to create a UDF like this?

Answer (score 0):

The library used by pyspark is `cpickle` which stands for cloud pickle and serializing libraries written in C is not supported by it yet.

If you want to parse xml use databricks XML parser instead and it'll be fast as well.